# Is this an appropriate use of Polymorphism?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Consider this syntactically correct(?) pseudocode:

```
class Event {
public:
    virtual int getID() const = 0;
    virtual int getSize() = 0;
    virtual void* getData() = 0;
    virtual void setData() = 0;
    //(I cannot define data at this level 'cos I don't know what it is yet)
}

class SpecialEvent : class Event {
public:
    virtual int getPGNID() const = 0;
    int getSourceAddress() {return source_address;}
    int setSourceAddress(int source_address) {this->source_address = source_address;}
protected:
    int source_address;
}

template <typename T, typename E>
class EventWrapper : public E {
    T data;
public:
    static int EVENT_ID;
    //implements everything in Event...EVENT_ID is assigned at runtime by some registry
}

class AnEvent : public EventWrapper<int, Event> {
     //public methods specific to AnEvent...
}

class AnotherEvent : public EventWrapper<long, SpecialEvent> {
    int getPGNID() const {static int ID = 10; return ID;}
}

class TheProcessingClass {
    AnEvent event1;
    AnotherEvent event2;

    void process(Event& e);
    void process(SpecialEvent& e);

    void doSomething() {
        process(event1);  //should invoke process(Event&)
        process(event2);  //should invoke process(SpecialEvent&)
    }
}
```

Essentially, I have a wrapper class that wraps data of type T and inherits from some type of `E` (in this case `Event` or `SpecialEvent`)...

I initially was going to create two wrapper classes `EventWrapper` and `SpecialEventWrapper` until I figured out that both classes would have the exact same code in it (as long as it was extending from some type of `Event`)

First off, this sounds like a policy-based design.  However, the `Events` don't have any special behavior...they just hold some data...   Am I abusing this pattern?

Second off, is there a better way to do this?  I'm oversimplifying things greatly here, but any insights will be appreciated...

**EDIT**
I updated my example...in short, the processing classes are listening for Events and should take action based on the Event.  I hope this helps...

Comment: +1 for "syntactically correct pseudocode" =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding process() as a member function of class event.

```
class Event {
    int getID() const;
    void process();
    //class stuff
}

class SpecialEvent : class Event {
    int getSpecialID() const;
    void process(); //special version of process()
    //class stuff
}


class TheProcessingClass {
    Event event1;
    SpecialEvent event2;

    void doSomething() {
        event1.process();
        event2.process();
    }
}
```

Comment: @T Reddy: So what? If you don't need it to be a POD, make it a member function.

Answer (score 0):

I've played with your code for a little while.
It looks to me that you are trying to do something very much like [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/any.html)

If not my main advice is to use a true abstract interface for both Event and SpecialEvent. The design you have is only partial polymorphism due to the fact that SpecialEvent has a method, and even more importantly an IDENTITY method, which does not override the Event::getId. That 'feels' very bad and I believe is guaranteed to lead you into difficulties later when you come to depend on the Id concept in any generic way.

In your design you need to establish a clear distinction between class (type) identity and object (instance) identity. So far you appear to be only working with object (instance) identity otherwise your id() method(s) would be static.
[RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) may be used for establishing class identity but depending on actual derived types is a classic anti-pattern and usually indicates broken polymorphism. I have never had need of RTTI, not even for logging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The key code to answer your question are the two process functions and what they do. Is it incorrect to pass a SpecialEvent or an EventWrapper that is derived from SpecialEvent to the `process(Event&)` function? If so, then this is not an appropriate use of polymorphism.

Comment: I don't think it is incorrect to pass a SpecialEvent to something that only handles Events...whatever is listening for Events may not care that it is of type SpecialEvent...